# If $A$ is a balanced and convex set, then $\lambda A + \mu A = (|\lambda| + |\mu|)A$?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I have proven that $\lambda A + \mu A \subset (|\lambda| + |\mu|)A$. How do I prove the reverse inclusion?

Comment: Write $\lvert\lambda\rvert = \lambda \cdot e^{i\psi}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for responding. Can I ask what to take $|\mu|$ equal to?